# How to query firestore data in Flutter where its field value is contained in local list variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Flutter app that shows events details at my university.
I'm trying to make a favorite system that lets the user pinned the events by saving its name to a local list variable. So on the favorite page, I'd like to query each entry where its name matches those in the local variable. For example, I have this favorite list

```
var fav = ['Event 1', 'Event 5']
```

Here's my code so far

```
Stream _queryDb() {

Query query = db.collection('Event').orderBy('Start_time');

slides = query.snapshots().map((list) => list.documents.map((doc) => doc.data));
}
```

This will query every entry in my firestore db

But I want my query to query the entry with the name 'Event 1' and 'Event 5'

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

PS. This is my first post on StackOverflow so I'm sorry if I'm not clear or I doesn't provide enough explanation/information.

Comment: Do the documents in the Event Collection have fields for the name of the event?

Comment: Please edit the question to show an example of the documents you're trying to query.  Where exactly is this name stored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```dart
List<String> events = ["Event 1", "Event 2"];
Query query = Firestore.instance
        .collection('Event')
        .where('name', whereIn: events)
        .orderBy('Start_time');
```

Comment: This also works very well! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `where` operator on your CollectionReference:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fav.length; i++){
    Query query = db.collection('Event').orderBy('Start_time').where('name', isEqualTo fav[i]);
    slides = query.snapshots().map((list) => list.documents.map((doc) => doc.data));
}
```

Assuming each field in the collection has a field called 'name', it will get the specific document.

Comment: I think this will be less efficient in case of a large list

Comment: Just looked at your answer. whereIn sounds like a much better option

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks a lot!